# Visual Studio indentation issue

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-mac

I'm using VS 8.5.3 version, the problem is that whenever I write a newline function, the parentheses can't always be aligned. The second bracket is always one more indent.

```
void  myfunc() { // when I press "enter" at here
```

it becomes:

```
void  myfunc() {

      }
```

instead of

```
void  myfunc() {

}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Really appreciated.

Comment: Isn't VS 8 a [_really_ old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) version? (15+ years)

Comment: It's VS version 8.5.3 for Mac. Tried pretty much all setting in Editor section still can't fix. sigh..

Comment: Have you tried with [.editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/editorconfig?view=vsmac-2019)? There are tons of settings, more than the linked article shows, however I have no idea how good the support is on Mac. See in [.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2019), look for indentation preferences. If you find a solution, I would like to encourage you to post and answer to your own question.